# MongoDB: Remove Sub-Array from Element where The Sub-Array is Empty

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am using Mongodb 4.0. I have documents like this:

```
db.ff.drop();
db.ff.insertMany([
    /* Document 1 */
    {
        "_id": "987",
        "customerProfiles": [
            {
                "freqShopper": []
            },
            {
                "freqShopper": []
            }
        ]
    },
    /* Document 2 */
    {
        "_id": "123123",
        "customerProfiles": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Smith",
                "freqShopper": [
                    {
                        "programName": "AS",
                        "number": "12345",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Mia",
                "lastName": "Lee",
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Alvin",
                "lastName": "Pepys",
                "freqShopper": []
            },
            {
                "freqShopper": []
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

I need this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "987",
    "customerProfiles" : [ ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "123123",
    "customerProfiles" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Smith",
            "freqShopper" : [
                {
                    "programName" : "AS",
                    "number" : "12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Mia",
            "lastName" : "Lee"
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Alvin",
            "lastName" : "Pepys"
        }
    ]
}
```

In other words, I need to:

1. remove any element from the array customerProfiles where freqShopper is the only field in the element, and
2. if there are other fields in the element, remove only the freqShopper array.

I've tried the following query:

```
db.ff.update({}, { $pull: { "customerProfiles": { "freqShopper": [] } } }, { multi: true })
```

But it removes all elements where the freqShopper array is empty. In this case, means the "Alvin Pepys" record is missing:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "987",
    "customerProfiles" : [ ]
},

/* 2 Alvin Pepys missing*/
{
    "_id" : "123123",
    "customerProfiles" : [
        {
            "firstName" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Smith",
            "freqShopper" : [
                {
                    "programName" : "AS",
                    "number" : "12345"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName" : "Mia",
            "lastName" : "Lee"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this:

```
    db.ff.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
        var arr = doc.customerProfiles;
        var length = arr.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (!(arr[i]["freqShopper"] && arr[i]["freqShopper"].length)) 
               { delete arr[i]["freqShopper"] }
        }
        db.ff.save(doc);
    });
    
    db.ff.update(
        {},
        { "$pull": { "customerProfiles": { "lastName": { "$exists": false } } } },
        { "multi": true }
    )
```